# Azure DevOps projects vs Visual Studio projects (that are in a single solution)

Tags: automated-tests, azure-devops, projects-and-solutions, microsoft-test-manager

I have created multiple Selenium projects in a single solution. These projects share a common project (Framwork that contains reusable methods, extensions etc). Now, I want to add test cases for each of these projects on Azure DevOps(formerly Visual Studio Team Services) and execute from test hub. How do I do that?

I have tried to create multiple projects  in Azure DevOps but each of the projects seems to have a repository of their own but all my code is in a single VS solution(for example, 3 VS projects in a single VS solution). Do I copy the same solution in all the ADO(Azure DevOps) repositories? Or is there another way I can put this solution on ADO and share it across all the ADO projects?

Comment: A Team Project and a Visual Studio project are **not** analogous. Think of a team project as *a portfolio of related applications*. All of your source code for an application (and for any related applications) should go in a single team project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to MSFT support on phone and they told me these different Selenium projects should be separated/maintained as Areas in a single AzureDevOps project. Different areas can be assigned different itearations and thus you can equate

Different Selenium Projects = Different Azure Dev Ops areas

Answer (score 0):

A Team Project and a Visual Studio project are **not** analogous. Think of a team project as *a portfolio of related applications*.

All of your source code for an application (and for any related applications) should go in a single team project.